# Does Dependency Injection (DI) rely on Interfaces?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, separation-of-concerns

This may seem obvious to most people, but I'm just trying to confirm that Dependency Injection (DI) relies on the use of Interfaces.

More specifically, in the case of a class which has a certain Interface as a parameter in its constructor or a certain Interface defined as a property (aka. Setter), the DI framework can hand over an instance of a concrete class to satisfy the needs of that Interface in that class. (Apologies if this description is not clear. I'm having trouble describing this properly because the terminology/concepts are still somewhat new to me.)

The reason I ask is that I currently have a class that has a dependency of sorts. Not so much an object dependency, but a URL. The class looks like this [C#]:

```
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
public partial class SomeLibraryService : SoapHttpClientProtocol 
{
        public SomeLibraryService() 
        {
            this.Url = "http://MyDomainName.com:8080/library-service/jse";
        }
}
```

The SoapHttpClientProtocol class has a Public property called `Url` (which is a plain old "string") and the constructor here initializes it to a hard-coded value.

Could I possibly use a DI framework to inject a different value at construction? I'm thinking not since `this.Url` isn't any sort of `Interface`; it's a `String`.

*[Incidentally, the code above was "auto-generated by wsdl", according to the comments in the code I'm working with. So I don't particularly want to change this code, although I don't see myself re-generating it either. So maybe changing this code is fine.]*

I could see myself making an alternate constructor that takes a string as a parameter and initializes `this.Url` that way, but I'm not sure that's the correct approach regarding keeping loosely coupled separation of concerns. (SoC)

Any advice for this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not required to use interfaces -- you could use concrete types or abstract base classes.   But many of the advantages of DI (such as being able to change an implementation of a dependancy) come when using interfaces.

Castle Windsor (the DI framework I know best), allows you to map objects in the IoC container to Interfaces, or to just names,  which would work in your case.

Comment: I'm giving you the green checkmark, but David's and Peter's answers were also very good as well. Thanks for clarifying that Interfaces are not required.

Comment: "...come when using interfaces" this is incorrect or misleading. I think either remove this or back it up with how using an abstract base class would stop me from changing the implementation of a dependency.

Comment: @LukePuplett: If you used a mocking framework to build objects for unit testing (one of the core justifications for DI), you would need to use an interface.

Comment: @JamesCurran No, like manually subclassing for polymorphism, mocking works within the same constraints; members must be abstract or virtual. As David calls out, DI is the act of supplying the dependencies to the class or system that is to be used, even if manually, without a automated DI container like Unity. Re your question, I don't use mocking libraries. I write really good fakes and I only test the _behaviour_ of the public API leaving me free to refactor often and easily. Mocking obscures tests and couples tests to implementation. Having to mock your own code is sign of a design flaw.

Answer (score 8):

DI really just means a class wont construct it's external dependencies and will not manage the lifetime of those dependencies. Dependencies can be injected either via constructor, or via method parameter. Interfaces or abstract types are common to clarify the contract the consumer expects from its dependency, however simple types can be injected as well in some cases.

For example, a class in a library might call HttpContext.Current internally, which makes arbitrary assumptions about the application the code will be hosted in. An DI version of the library method would expect a HttpContext instance to be injected via parameter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency Injection is a way of organizing your code.  Maybe some of your confusion comes from the fact that there is not one official way to do it.  It can be achieved using "regular" c# code , or by using a framework like Castle Windsor.  Sometimes (often?) this involves using interfaces.  No matter how it is achieved, the big picture goal of DI is usually to make your code easier to test and easier to modify later on.

If you were to inject the URL in your example via a constructor, that could be considered "manual" DI.  The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) on DI has more examples of manual vs framework DI.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Some of the confusion comes from there not being a standardized way of doing it. DI has been presented to me via the "Pro ASP.net MVC Framework" book (by Sanderson) and every example shown uses Interfaces, so my conclusion was that it only worked on Interfaces, but logically it didn't make sense in my head, so I had to ask. Sanderson talks about Castle Windsor in his first book, but now uses Ninject in his 2nd Edition (which just came off the printing presses last week.) And yes, I'm beginning to realize that DI helps greatly with Unit Testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer with a focus on using interfaces in .NET applications. Polymorphism in .NET can be achieved through virtual or abstract methods, or interfaces.

In all cases, there is a method signature with no implementation at all or an implementation that can be overridden.

The 'contract' of a function (or even a property) is defined but how the method is implemented, the logical guts of the method can be different at runtime, determined by which subclass is instantiated and passed-in to the method or constructor, or set on a property (the act of 'injection').

The official .NET type design guidelines advocate using abstract base classes over interfaces since they have better options for evolving them after shipping, can include convenience overloads and are better able to self-document and communicate correct usage to implementers.

However, care must be taken not to add any logic. The temptation to do so has burned people in the past so many people use interfaces - many other people use interfaces simply because that's what the programmers sitting around them do.

It's also interesting to point out that while DI itself is rarely over-used, using a framework to perform the injection is quite often over-used to the detriment of increased complexity, a chain-reaction can take place where more and more types are needed in the container even though they are never 'switched'.

IoC frameworks should be used sparingly, usually only when you need to swap out objects at runtime, according to the environment or configuration. This usually means switching major component "seams" in the application such as the repository objects used to abstract your data layer.

For me, the real power of an IoC framework is to switch implementation in places where you have no control over creation. For example, in ASP.NET MVC, the creation of the controller class is performed by the ASP.NET framework, so injecting anything is impossible. The ASP.NET framework has some hooks that IoC frameworks can use to 'get in-between' the creation process and perform their magic.

Luke

Comment: See Binary Breaking Changes in this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/breaking-changes which recommends using abstract base classes over interfaces.